# MySQL version appears to be inconsistent?

Tags: mysql, percona-server

I have recently upgraded mysqld (percona server) from 5.5.60-38.12 to 5.5.62-38.14. This is on Debian, and the upgrade was done like this:

```
# apt-get update
# apt-get upgrade
```

I am surprised to find that the version is reported differently internally from what I get on the command line:

```
db3 root = mysql -V
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.62-38.14, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.1
mysql> select version();
+------------------+
| version()        |
+------------------+
| 5.5.60-38.12-log |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Is this normal? Or do I need to do something to fix this issue?

***Edit:*** I've allso checked the installed packages:

```
db3 root = dpkg -l | grep percona
ii  libperconaserverclient18        5.5.62-rel38.14-1.stretch         amd64        Percona Server database client library
ii  percona-server-client-5.5       5.5.62-rel38.14-1.stretch         amd64        Percona Server database client binaries
ii  percona-server-common-5.5       5.5.62-rel38.14-1.stretch         amd64        Percona Server database common files
ii  percona-server-server-5.5       5.5.62-rel38.14-1.stretch         amd64        Percona Server database server binaries
ii  percona-toolkit                 3.1.0-2.stretch                   amd64        Advanced MySQL and system command-line tools
ii  percona-xtrabackup              2.3.10-1.stretch                  amd64        Open source backup tool for InnoDB and XtraDB
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question, in case other might benefit.

The explanation, it turns out, was that although the upgrade succeeded, the restart of the daemon had failed silently. It took a `kill -9` and `systemctl start mysql` to sort that out.

Answer (score 0):

This is little incorrect steps to upgrade mysql version.

Although, to overcome this you can try below steps if it fixes this issue.

1. Try mysql_upgrade,

`mysql_upgrade -uuser -ppassword`

2. Restart mysql instance,

`systemctl restart mysql`